# Pandas exploding out columns with groupby is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` with a column `parsed xml` that contains a list of dictionaries for each row with the parsed attributes. It looks like this:

```
   id  type  length  parsed    
0  1   A     144     [{'key1':'value1'},{'key1':'value2', 'key2':'value3'},...]
1  1   B     20      [{'key1':'value4'},{'key2':'value5'},...]
2  4   A     54      [{'key3':'value6'},...]
```

I am using the following to expand out those dictionaries into additional columns.

```
s = df['parsed xml'].explode()
t = (df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index = s.index).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()), /
    lsuffix = '_x', rsuffix = '_y')).applymap(lambda x: x[0] if (type(x)==list and len(x)==1) else x)
```

This gives me a data frame like this, which is how I want it:

```
   id  type  length  key1             key2     key3
0  1   A     144     [value1,value2]  value3
1  1   B     20      value4           value5
2  4   A     54                                value6
```

The issue is that the code to get to this data frame take about 45 seconds for 5,000 records, but seemingly goes on forever with it is used on 12,000 records. It seems like the `groupby` is causing this, but can this be made more efficient?

Comment: Could you share the 12k records to replicate the issue?

Comment: Most likely the issue here is the `applymap`, followed by the `agg`.  Are the combinations of `id`, `type` and `length` guaranteed to be unique per row?

Comment: @joaoavf Unfortunately I can't. I just seems to be exponential in terms of time.

Comment: @r.ook I tried remove the applymap, agg, and groubpy piece by piece, and once groupby was introduced was when it started slowing down.

Comment: @r.ook You're right, it seems to be the `agg` that's causing the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Can you share some more context for this? It's difficult to optimize things otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can slightly change your method to optimize a bit, using `stack` and `unstack` and perform the `applymap` on only the column you create. like this:

```
s = df['parsed'].explode()
df_join = (pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index = s.index)
             .stack()
             .groupby(level=[0,1])
             .agg(list)
             .apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x)==1 else x)
             .unstack(fill_value='')
          )
t = df.join(df_join)
print (t) # I did not used exactly your input
  id                                             parsed              key1  \
0  a  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key1': 'value2', 'key2'...  [value1, value2]   
1  b           [{'key1': 'value4'}, {'key2': 'value5'}]            value4   
2  c                               [{'key3': 'value6'}]                     

     key2    key3  
0  value3          
1  value5          
2          value6
```

Now in terms of performance, I see an improvement of 2 on a dataframe of 3 rows like here, but the improvement increase with the size (it is 6 time faster with 3K rows). This increase in speed will depend on the number of elements you have in each list in the column parse and the number of different keys as well I guess